# Protractor error when running protractor conf.js

Tags: protractor

I am getting an error while execution command protractor conf.js

I am trying to run the sample project code available at
https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example

My error is

```
D:\Users\protractor_example-master
>protractor conf.js
[13:30:33] E/configParser - error code: 105
[13:30:33] E/configParser - description: failed loading configuration file conf.
js

D:\Users\xxxxxx\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:130
            throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configurat
ion file ' + filename);
```

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about ur problem and please do not try just get a sample code and run. Follow a tutorial and do it urself. U won't have this kkind of problems if u do so. :)

Comment: Also, u get this error when protractor cannot find your configuration file.

Comment: According to some answer-comments, this question is resolved. Can you add or mark an answer, if that's the case?
Were you able to resolve your follow-up-problem with `jasmine-spec-reporter` or is that still pending?

Answer (score 5):

You have to go into the directory where you have your config file :

```
cd /yourPath/
```

Then run your file.

Comment: I am running from the path where files resides

D:\Users\XXXXXX\Downloads\protractor_example-master\protractor_example-master

Comment: and both your files testspec.js and config.js are here ?

Comment: Thanks for your help  actually protractor-html-screenshot-reporter package was not available on my system. Error description was not clear. After commenting one by one line I could know the reason. Now error have been changed Error: Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-spec-reporter'. I have added path also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter then it should be installed **locally to the folder** where your project scripts and conf.js is present.

I was getting the below error

```
H:\protractorDemo>protractor conf.js

**Error:**
[05:20:41] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[05:20:41] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file con
f.js
[05:20:41] E/configParser - Error: Cannot find module 'protractor-jasmine2-html-
reporter'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
```

and after installing it using command

```
npm install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter --save-dev
```

on folder 'H:\protractorDemo>' it started working fine.